# Can you link a Google+ share to a Google+ account, like you can on Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: javascript, html, api, share, google-plus

When using the Facebook Feed Dialog to give users a way to share a URL, you must supply the app ID of your Facebook app. This app is then referenced when users share your URL, e.g.:

[image: A Facebook app referenced in the feed dialog]

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

When sharing a URL to Twitter via their web intents, you can supply a Twitter account to be mentioned in the tweet, using the `via` parameter.

- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

Is there an equivalent mechanism when sharing on Google+, either via their Share button or Share link? I can’t see one listed in their documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar system in place, although it is done through the more advanced [Interactive Posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) share button. This will create something that resembles a share with your application name on it, the link that is being shared, as well as a "call to action" button that can take a specific action separate from linking to the page. This is more advanced than the +1 or Share buttons, since it does require at least a little bit of developer knowledge and registration of the website/app with Google's developer console.

Comment: Aha, yes I see. You can also suggest prefill text for the user’s share message with interactive posts as well. Excellent. It does look like a more involved set-up, but it’s good to see something along those lines can be done.